# images in css with webpack 3

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass

I have went over every stack overflow post regarding this issue, and still have been unable to solve this issue. I cannot get background-image: url() to work for the life of me. I am not kidding when I say I have gone through every post. Why is webpack so frustrating when it comes to this simple task? Below is my modules in my webpack.config. Please someone help I have been at this for two days.

```js
 module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel-loader']},
            {test: /bootstrap\/js\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' },
            {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'},
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!scss')
            },
            {test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
            {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
            {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
            {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=images/svg+xml" },
            {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, loaders: [
                'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
                'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false',
                'url-loader?limit=90000000&name=src/images/[name].[ext]'
            ]}

        ]
    }
```

Comment: Did you check the generated code?

Comment: What does "cannot get to work" mean?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? Are you talking about the bundle.js file?

Comment: I am using an background-image: url() in my scss file. I get no errors, but I do not get the background image either.

Comment: Can we see the code where you reference the image?

Comment: I am referencing in a scss file like so.

  background-image: url("/images/logoBack.png");
  height: 1000px;

Comment: The images reside in an images folder that is in the src folder of my project src>images>image.png. The scss file is in a different folder src>styles>scss>partials>.scss_file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `resolve-url-loader` to be able to use relative paths in `scss`, here an example of how to use it:

```
module: {
  rules: [{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: true,
            importLoaders: 1,
            localIdentName: '[local]'
          }
        }, {
          loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true
          }
        }, {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            outputStyle: 'compressed',
            sourceMap: true
          }
        }
      ]

    })
  }, {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
    loaders: [{
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[path][name].[hash:base64:5].[ext]',
        publicPath: '/',
        outputPath: 'img/'
      }
    }, {
      loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
      options: {
        gifsicle: {
          interlaced: false
        },
        optipng: {
          optimizationLevel: 7
        },
        pngquant: {
          quality: '65-90',
          speed: 4
        },
        mozjpeg: {
          progressive: true,
          quality: 70
        }
      }
    }]
  }]
}
```

> Pay attention to the `options` in `file-loader` that configuration tells webpack where to output the images.

In [this commit](https://github.com/arkgast/react-firebase-starter/commit/923e782e70a8b532657e98597ffd757ddeb1f41c) there is a running example.

Comment: so public path is '/' in your example. Are you saying I should have '/src/images'? That is the path to my images.

Comment: I think would be better if you use something like this in your `.scss` file: `background-image: url('images/logoBack.png')`-